# Can I add a promise/unmaterialized record to a hasMany while I wait for it to be retrieved?

Tags: ember-data

Back in the unversioned Ember Data days (e.g. "rev 12" maybe) I'm pretty sure you could do this:

```
var comment = App.Comment.find(42); // Already exists, but not yet loaded...
post.get('comments').addObject(comment);
```

Because `App.Comment.find(42)` would return an `App.Comment` object, albeit one with no fields populated except it's ID. (I don't remember the details of how you'd then save the `App.Post`--i.e. if you could or couldn't save it until the comment object was completely loaded…I never got that far.)

Why this was neat is that if your template rendered `post.comments`, a new row/div would appear immediately that could check `isLoaded` to display a loading indicator and show instantly that a new record was attached while waiting for the record's data to load. This is/was a selling point of Ember/Ember Data, and one I really like.

But this doesn't work now in 1.0.0-<strike>beta.2</strike> <strike>beta.4</strike> beta.5:

```
var comment = controller.get('store').find('comment', 42);
post.get('comments').addObject(comment); // Fails
```

Because `controller.get('store').find('comment', 42)` returns a *promise*, and if I try to add it to the hasMany it complains that I can only add `App.Comment` objects to the relationship.

Is it still possible to do something like this, so that my template which renders the comments immediately updates with a new record, but asynchronously populates its data?

(Please ignore that it doesn't make sense to add an already existing comment to a post--using the ubiquitous example scenario is easier than posting all my model code. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I came up with at least one way that does it:

```js
var comment = controller.get('store').find('comment', 42);
var inFlightRecord = controller.get('store').getById('comment', 42);
controller.get('comments').addObject(inFlightRecord);
```

To be safer, maybe:

```js
var comment = controller.get('store').find('comment', 42);
var inFlightRecord = controller.get('store').getById('comment', 42);
if(inFlightRecord){ // should be null if it isn't in the store
    controller.get('comments').addObject(inFlightRecord);
} else {
    // add a then block to the promise to make sure it gets added later
}
```

It seems that `getById` returns the "unloaded" object like we used to get from `App.Comment.find(42)`, and the object still has an `isLoaded` property you can check to show loading status in your template.

I'm not sure if this is supposed to be supported behavior that I can rely on going forward (I suppose arguably nothing is, until 1.0 release), but it seems to work. I even checked that the object returned by `getById` `===` the object fulfilled in the promise. So this seems to be a good solution.

Anyone see a problem with this, or have a better way?

Comment: your method seems to be the only way for now. good one by the way